# Directive called from partial not working

Tags: angularjs-directive

I'm not sure if its because I'm trying to use a directive inside a partial but I cannot get a simple directive element click event to fire.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
         <tabbed-Panel1 class="bottomTabPanel">
             TEST CLICK HERE!
          </tabbed-Panel1>
    </body>
</html>
```

js: DIRECTIVE

```
angular.module('directives', ['basemodule'])


  .directive('tabbedPanel1',function() {

        debugger;

        restrict:"E",
        return {

                   link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

                        elem.bind('click', function() {
                           //never gets here!
                           debugger;


                         });
                     }
            };
});
```

Comment: Ok part of the issue was formatting of tabbedPanel1 for in-markup use. So in the html it had to be : tabbed-Panel1. The click event is still not responding though, hmmmm

Comment: Ok the second issue was I was missing : restrict:"E",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, part of the issue was formatting of tabbedPanel1 for in-markup use. So in the HTML it had to be: `tabbed-Panel1`

The issue regarding the click event was solved by adding: `restrict:"E"`